# php file_get_contents Let’s Encrypt can't open url

Tags: php, ssl, encryption

I have problem code php file_get_contents open URL have ssl Let’s Encrypt

```
$arrContextOptions = array(
    "ssl" => array(
        "verify_peer" => false,
        "verify_peer_name" => false,
    ),
);
echo file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));
```

result :

> Warning: file_get_contents(): SSL: Connection reset by peer in
>   /var/www/vhosts/com/test.php on line 8
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto in
>   /var/www/vhosts/com/test.php on line 8
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(url): failed to open stream: operation
>   failed in /var/www/vhosts/com/test.php on line 8

but can open any ssl url not use Let’s Encrypt

Comment: Looks more like an issue with that sites server, as if _that_ is unable to communicate...

Comment: [curl](http://php.net/curl) is a good alternative in such a case

Comment: oh, i found problem this have firewall some domain

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51873495/simplexml-load-file-to-read-remote-xml-via-url-connection-reset-by-peer