# simplexml_load_file to read remote xml via url, connection reset by peer

Tags: php, https, cron, simplexml

When i tried to read a the xml output from the below url,over a cron job in godaddy shared hosting.

```
https://www.bluedart.com/servlet/RoutingServlet?handler=tnt&action=custawbquery&loginid=MAA00001&format=xml&lickey=a28f0bb8690c75ce3368bb1c76ea98bc&verno=1.3&scan=1&awb=awb&numbers=14539611450
```

i get the following error

> Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: SSL: Connection reset by peer in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/indiagsl/cron/test.php on line
>   32
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: Failed
>   to enable crypto in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/indiagsl/cron/test.php on line
>   32
>
> Warning:
>   simplexml_load_file(https://www.bluedart.com/servlet/RoutingServlet?handler=tnt&action=custawbquery&loginid=MAA01849&awb=awb&format=xml&lickey=5eeb55bdce11d065649a32f7e6f6463c&verno=1.3&scan=1&numbers=50545219152)
>   [function.simplexml-load-file]: failed to open stream: operation
>   failed

My code is as follows

```
$url = "https://www.bluedart.com/servlet/RoutingServlet?handler=tnt&action=custawbquery&loginid=MAA00001&format=xml&lickey=a28f0bb8690c75ce3368bb1c76ea98bc&verno=1.3&scan=1&awb=awb&numbers=14539611450";
        try {
            echo $i."-";
            $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
            if(false === $xml) {
                echo "Failed Loading XML";
                foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $errors) {
                    echo "\t", $errors->message ."##";
                }
                $updateFlag=0;
            }
          } catch(Exception $e) {
            echo "ERROR::";
            print_r($e);
        }
```

Kindly help me with your valuable inputs.
Thanks

Comment: Changing your link to `http` instead of `https` makes it work. It seems like they don't have their ssl certificate set up quite right. Also: I'm not sure if that's real customer data, but if it is you might want to remove the link so the whole world doesn't see it.

Comment: Thanks, The links are dummy for testing purpose. But i have already tried that , changing https, to http, It does not fix it when running it as cron job.

Comment: Are you sure the error you get in your cronjob is the same one then? The error you posted really points to the SSL part. Maybe you can print your `$url` as well in your catch clause to be 100% sure what url is being called.

Comment: Ok, Checking now. Kindly give me few mins.

Comment: Looks like, the urls are changed to https, Now any suggestion, how to include certificate, when using simplexml_load_file...

Comment: Use curl or guzzle to retrieve the xml document. Then instead of `$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);` do `$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_str);` where `$xml_str` is the one you retrieved via curl or guzzle

Comment: You really **shouldn't be posting** an url that has your loginid and licensekey for a service on SO.

Comment: Has the answer solved your problem?

Comment: Kotagiri ya?...

Comment: Yes, from kotagiri

Answer (score 0):

Adding a simple function using `curl` to retrieve the document, and changing `simple_xml_load_file` to `simple_xml_load_string` should do the trick.

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true); //to get the errors from libxml_get_errors()

$url = "https://www.bluedart.com/servlet/RoutingServlet?handler=tnt&action=custawbquery&loginid=MAA00001&format=xml&lickey=a28f0bb8690c75ce3368bb1c76ea98bc&verno=1.3&scan=1&awb=awb&numbers=14539611450";

$i = 2; //to get rid of notice error. remove this line

function getXml($url) {
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "/path/to/cacert.pem"); //absolute path to certificate
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "c:/path/to/cacert.pem");
    $curl_response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $curl_response;
}

try {
    echo $i."-";
     $xml_file = getXml($url);
     $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_file);
     if(false === $xml) {
         echo "Failed Loading XML";
         foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $errors) {
             echo "\t", $errors->message ."##";
         }
         $updateFlag=0;
     }
     // else die(print_r($xml));
 } catch(Exception $e) {
     echo "ERROR::";
     print_r($e);
 }
```

uncommenting `else die(print_r($xml));` gives below

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [Shipment] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [WaybillNo] => 14539611450
                )
            [Status] => Incorrect Waybill number or No Information
            [StatusType] => NF
        )

)
```

> **Note** This function is for reply purposes. In real world scenarios, I **strongly** advice you to use [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle)

[cacert.pem from curl.haxx.se](http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem)

Comment: The above code fails, with the message "Failed Loading XML". Any suggestion on including certificate , which could be copied from browser?

Comment: What do you need a certificate for?

Comment: Its an SSL error, so thought providing a ssl certificate would resolve the problem..

Comment: I have updated my answer to use a certificate, however it should work with or without it..

Comment: It must be something with your machine. It works on my machine. I'll update with the details though

Comment: @Linton what is the output of `libxml_get_errors()` ?